# Iterate through List of List of Objects in extendedDataTable

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

Is it possible to loop through  an arrayList using c:forEach in rich:extendedDataTable.

I have a model like

```
Person {
    String name;
    String address;
    List<String> phoneNum;
}
```

The table row should display columns of name, address and comma separated phoneNumbers.

How do I create another loop when going through List using extendedDataTable

Comment: If I can limit the phoneNumbers to 2, then is it also possible to display only 4 columns with name, address, ph-1 and ph-2 columns?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the richfaces a4j:repeat tag to iterate over the phoneNum list.  Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
<rich:column>
<f:facet name="header">
 <h:outputText value="Phone #s" />
</f:facet>
<ul style="padding: 0px; list-style-type: none;">
<a4j:repeat value="#{person.phoneNum}" var="phoneNum">
  <li>#{phoneNum}</li>
</a4j:repeat>
</ul>
</rich:column>
```